# different design for portrait and landscape mode in android

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-orientation, orientation-changes

Hi i have created two fragments on single layout.

In layout-land :

fragments need to display horizontally.

In layout-port :
fragments need to display vertically.

Now i have to run the app on portrait mode means displaying the fragment vertically.
now i have to rotate these to landscape mode means displaying the fragments vertically only.

At the same time i have to run the app on landscape mode means displaying the fragment horizontally.now i have to rotate these to portrait mode means displaying the fragment horizontally.

But i wish to display the output like:

i have to run the app on portrait mode means displaying the fragment vertically.
now i have to rotate these to landscape mode means displaying the fragments horizontally.

At the same time i have to run the app on landscape mode means displaying the fragment horizontally.now i have to rotate these to portrait mode means displaying the fragment vertically.

How can i do ???

Why am getting the result like above.please give me any suggestions .

**EDIT:**

**layout-land : fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/_listDetails"

>
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pos"
        android:src="@drawable/ref_off" />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
android:background="#414042"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:name="com.notch.notchbolly.MainActivity"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="0.83"

  />
  <View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    />
 <fragment
  android:id="@+id/subcate"
  android:name="com.notch.notchbolly.SubCate"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**layout-port: fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/_listDetails"

 >
  <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pos"
        android:src="@drawable/ref_off" />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
android:background="#414042"
android:id="@+id/orien"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:name="com.notch.notchbolly.MainActivity"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="200dp"

  />
 <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    />
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/subcate"
  android:name="com.notch.notchbolly.SubCate"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />


   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my AndroidListFragmentActivity:

```
    public  class AndroidListFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity  {


       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment);

    ImageView refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(AndroidListFragmentActivity.this, AndroidListFragmentActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                } 
            }); 



                }
            @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged ( Configuration newConfig )
              {
              super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        }

        }
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FMn4FEv12M check this video.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:configChanges="orientation"`  from the activity declaration in manifest file.

Comment: i have removed these its worked perfectly...but taked loading time...i need to display the different Ui without taking loading time when the orientation changes..

Comment: When the orientation is changed, the layout is destroyed and recreated with the resources for the new orientaion. so it takes little loading time

Comment: no...here my activity takes too much of time...here i have to change orientation means the whole activity is loaded again..i didn't need like these.i need to display without loading time

Comment: also i having listview on my first fragment.2nd fragment having selected list item...that selected item ly shows after orientation changes also.but i have removed android:configChanges="orientation" means getting the first item ly ..didn't display selected item..so orientation is performs reload the activity again.

Comment: @user2218667 have you found any solution for this without reloading the activity? I am stuck with the same issue.